# Developing .NETCore projects in Visual Studio for Mac and Windows

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, multiplatform, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to work on the same C# .NETCore codebase in both VS for mac and regular VS Enterprise 2015 (Windows).

I made a .NETCore app in VS for Mac and tried to open the project in VS for Win, but the one-way project upgrade dialog appears in VS for Win, so no multiplatform development joy? (After accepting the dialog to do a one-way upgrade, my Program.cs file does not appear in the Project Explorer... wtf)

Also tried to open an ASP.NET MVC project (made in VS for mac) on Windows VS, that worked (and back)!

How do you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with the latest version of VS for Mac (preview 4, 7.0) and Visual Studio 2017 this should work properly.

Both versions support updating projects from the old .xproj + project.json format to new .csproj that has returned msbuild support.

I tried creating projects on VS for Mac and vice versa and they seem to work ok on both platforms.

However, please ensure that you have the following installed:

- .Net Core SDK 1.1 (latest one)
- Openssl (OSX only)
- Latest Mono version (otherwise builds will fail on OSX)

Comment: Be aware that all external references have to come as NuGet (I guess). We tried it once with a project that had references to a folder that all our developers have on their drive, but that didn't work as Mac (of course) doesn't know C:\. Don't know about network shares, didn't try